# Image button inside search field?

Tags: css, button, textfield

I was wondering how websites like bing.com or wolframalpha.com create their search buttons inside of of the text field? If you go to each website, you can see clearly what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: the submit button (with transparent background) is above the input field.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Get yourself Firebug as a plugin for Firefox.  You can click on elements on the screen and see their CSS.  It'll teach you LOADS of info about CSS.  They actually use a negative margin to get that sucker to float over on Bing.com.

http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. There seems to be some difference in positioning between Opera & Chrome (the 2 browsers I've tested it in). Any way to specify a position specifically for a browser?

Comment: Hmmm...can't comment specifically.  Can you paste some of your CSS into your original post and I'll have a look.  Just paste the selectors that are in the immediate area to the search field.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the code, it works fine in Opera, but no other browser.

```
submit_form {
    background:transparent url(submit.png) no-repeat;
    border:0 none;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size:0px;
    text-decoration:none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: -25px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: This should be put back into the original post. You should be able to edit it, then delete this post when it's there.

Comment: The original post was submitted on an unregistered account, so I couldn't go back and edit it I'm afraid.